# Powershell does not output wrapper brackets when saving json file

Tags: json, database, powershell

Currently im writing a function to remove from an array and then save to a database. When I write the output it does not put the wrapper (This ->[]) around the file. This makes the json file unreadable. Wondering if im missing anything

```
    $ArrayIndex = $script:jsonDB.username.IndexOf($UserNametextBox.text)
    $script:jsonDB = $script:jsonDB | Where-Object{$_ -ne $script:jsonDB[$ArrayIndex]}
    $script:jsonDB | ConvertTo-Json -Depth $ArrayIndex -Compress|
    Set-Content C:\Support\HardwareCollection.json
    $script:TableData = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $script:TableData.AddRange($script:jsonDB)
    $script:datagridview.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
    $script:datagridview.DataSource= $script:TableData
    $script:datagridview.Refresh
```

Here is a copy of the working DB

```
[{"Date":"09/30/2021 10:19:34 -05:00","Username":"Username1000"}]
```

Here is what it looks like when it saves an unreadable json file

```
{"Date":"09/30/2021 10:19:34 -05:00","Username":"Username1000"}
```

Huge thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pipe a single object (or a single-item array) to `ConvertTo-Json`, it's going to assume that the root object is a scalar, even though it might have been contained in an array or list-like type when you piped it in (the cmdlet has no way of knowing).

In order to fix this, pass an array or list *directly* to the command instead of piping the input to it:

```
ConvertTo-Json @($script:jsonDB) -Depth $ArrayIndex -Compress | ...
```

Since the cmdlet now receives an explicit reference to an array (as opposed to receiving the members of the array, 1 by 1, via the pipeline), it knows that the root object should be an array too, and you'll get consistent results regardless of how many objects `$script:jsonDB` contains

Comment: Thanks for the help this resolved my issue immediately!!!